# restframework 'tuple' object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-gis

Django throws the next exception:

restframework 'tuple' object has no attribute '_meta'

Model

```
class BDetail(models.Model):
   lat = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
   lng = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)

   class Meta:
       # managed = False
       db_table = 'b_detail'
```

View

```
from .models import BDetail
from .serializers import BDetailSerializer
from rest_framework import viewsets

class BDetailList(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
        queryset = BDetail.objects.all()
        serializer_class = BDetailSerializer
```

urls

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from bdetail import views
from rest_framework import routers

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'bdetail', views.BDetailList)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls), name='bdetail')
]
```

serializers

```
from .models import BDetail
from rest_framework import serializers

class BDetailSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = BDetail,
        fields = ('lat', 'lng')
```

Environment:

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://apiix.verinmuebles.dev/v1/bdetail/

Traceback:

> File
>   "/var/www/verinmuebles/current/Env/api/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py"
>   in inner
>     39.             response = get_response(request)
>
> File
>   "/var/www/verinmuebles/current/Env/api/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File
>   "/var/www/verinmuebles/current/Env/api/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/var/www/verinmuebles/current/Env/api/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py"
>   in wrapped_view
>     58.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/var/www/verinmuebles/current/Env/api/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py"
>   in view
>     87.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/var/www/verinmuebles/current/Env/api/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py"
>   in dispatch
>     474.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)
>
> File
>   "/var/www/verinmuebles/current/Env/api/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py"
>   in handle_exception
>     434.             self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
>
> File
>   "/var/www/verinmuebles/current/Env/api/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py"
>   in dispatch
>     471.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/var/www/verinmuebles/current/Env/api/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py"
>   in list
>     45.             return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
>
> File
>   "/var/www/verinmuebles/current/Env/api/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py"
>   in data
>     701.         ret = super(ListSerializer, self).data
>
> File
>   "/var/www/verinmuebles/current/Env/api/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py"
>   in data
>     240.                 self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
>
> File
>   "/var/www/verinmuebles/current/Env/api/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py"
>   in to_representation
>     619.             self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable
>
> File
>   "/var/www/verinmuebles/current/Env/api/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py"
>   in to_representation
>     460.         fields = self._readable_fields
>
> File
>   "/var/www/verinmuebles/current/Env/api/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py"
>   in **get**
>     35.         res = instance.**dict**[self.name] = self.func(instance)
>
> File
>   "/var/www/verinmuebles/current/Env/api/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py"
>   in _readable_fields
>     354.             field for field in self.fields.values()
>
> File
>   "/var/www/verinmuebles/current/Env/api/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py"
>   in fields
>     340.             for key, value in self.get_fields().items():
>
> File
>   "/var/www/verinmuebles/current/Env/api/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py"
>   in get_fields
>     946.         info = model_meta.get_field_info(model)
>
> File
>   "/var/www/verinmuebles/current/Env/api/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/utils/model_meta.py"
>   in get_field_info
>     36.     opts = model._meta.concrete_model._meta
>
> Exception Type: AttributeError at /v1/bdetail/ Exception Value:
>   'tuple' object has no attribute '_meta'

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You are having the `,` after the name of `BDetail` model in `BDetailSerializer` serializer. Remove that and your code will work.

**Suggestion**: Inherit `serializers.ModelSerializer` in your `BDetailSerializer` serializer instead of `serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer` i.e. :

```
class BDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = BDetail
        fields = ('lat', 'lng')
```

Comment: Updated the answer. It is not working because you are having the `,` after the name of `BDetail` model in your `BDetailSerializer` serializer.

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri, thank you so much for your sharp eye. the ',' was my problem, it was messing the tuple structure! Right on!

Answer (score 20):

Just wanted to add a potential case where such a thing might happen. In case you are using `get_or_create`, keep in mind that this method returns a tuple, and not just the object.

As an example:

```
book = Book.objects.get_or_create(pk=123)
serializer = BookSerializer(book, request.data)
if serializer.is_valid():
    serializer.save() # <-- Right here you would get the same error
```

The problem is fixed by unpacking the tuple:

```
book, created = Book.objects.get_or_create(pk=123)

# or this way if you do not need to know if it was created or not
book, _ = Book.objects.get_or_create(pk=123)
```

Comment: useful for those like me with enough forgetfulness

Answer (score 2):

The problem is on the serializer, remove the ',' in `model = BDetail,` and the error will be gone. What you did there was essentially cast BDetail as a tuple.

Answer (score 0):

Use get_or_create() method instead of get_object_or_404 ()
When u r creating update view and use ", _"  after the object for avoiding "tuple object has no _meta".

Like this 
Obj = ModelClass.objects.get(pk=123)
This obj will raise error if it is None 
instead:
Use this :
obj, _ = ModelClass.objects.get_or_create(pk=123)
This method check if 123 exists in modelClass.pk get it   or if doesn't exist 123, create one 123 in the table,  save it and then get it .